# photo gallery works on gae appspot but not on 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, image-gallery

When I deploy my app on app engine the gallery works ( http://mark-smith-app.appspot.com/projects/ ) but it doesn't work offline..

I want to get my gallery working with the following command:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" .
```

When I open chrome and go to 127.0.0.1/projects/ it shows the gallery but only the first image displays, the rest of the images in the gallery are "black".

I downloaded the gallery from http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/

The gallery I downloaded comes with an example **index4.html** which works when I open it with chrome.

I copied everything from index4.html into my google app engines projects.html and changed made a static directory for the css, js and images.

here is app.yaml:

```
application: mark-smith-app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

I also went to 127.0.0.1/projects and went "view source" and copied it into html1.txt

I also copied "view source" from index4.html into html2.txt

I got the following results from the following python differ script:

```
f1 = open('html1.txt')
f2 = open('html2.txt')

from difflib import ndiff,IS_CHARACTER_JUNK



delta = ndiff([i.strip()+"\n" for i in f1],[i.strip()+"\n" for i in f2])

for line in delta:
    print line,
```

outputs:

```
*** Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***
>>> 

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Awkward Showcase - Demo #4</title>
- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
?                              ^ ---------
+ <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
?                              ^
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
- <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/jquery.aw-showcase.js"></script>
?                                     -------------
+ <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.aw-showcase.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(window).ready(function()
  {
  $("#showcase").awShowcase(
  {
  content_width:            700,
  fit_to_parent:            false,
  auto:                 true,
  interval:             3000,
  continuous:               false,
  loading:              true,
  tooltip_width:            200,
  tooltip_icon_width:       32,
  tooltip_icon_height:  32,
  tooltip_offsetx:      18,
  tooltip_offsety:      0,
  arrows:                   true,
  buttons:              true,
  btn_numbers:          false,
  keybord_keys:         true,
  mousetrace:               false, /* Trace x and y coordinates for the mouse */
  pauseonover:          true,
  stoponclick:          true,
  transition:               'fade', /* hslide/vslide/fade */
  transition_speed:     500,
  transition_delay:     300,
  show_caption:         'onhover', /* onload/onhover/show */
  thumbnails:               true,
  thumbnails_position:  'outside-last', /* outside-last/outside-first/inside-last/inside-first */
  thumbnails_direction: 'horizontal', /* vertical/horizontal */
  thumbnails_slidex:        0, /* 0 = auto / 1 = slide one thumbnail / 2 = slide two thumbnails / etc. */
  dynamic_height:           true, /* For dynamic height to work in webkit you need to set the width and height of images in the source. Usually works to only set the dimension of the first slide in the showcase. */
  speed_change:         false, /* Set to true to prevent users from swithing more then one slide at once. */
  viewline:             false /* If set to true content_width, thumbnails, transition and dynamic_height will be disabled. As for dynamic height you need to set the width and height of images in the source. */
  });
  });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="menu"><a href="index.html">Demo #1</a> (Normal) | <a href="index2.html">Demo #2</a> (Vertical thumnbails) | <a href="index3.html">Demo #3</a> (Horizontal thumbnails) | <a href="index4.html" class="active">Demo #4</a> (Dynamic height) | <a href="index5.html">Demo #5</a> (Hundred percent) | <a href="index6.html">Demo #6</a> (Viewline)</div>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <div style="width: 700px; margin: auto;">

  <!-- This is the button used to switch between One Page and Slideshow. -->
  <p><a id="awOnePageButton" href="#"><span class="view-page">View As One Page</span><span class="view-slide">View As Slideshow</span></a></p>

  <div id="showcase" class="showcase">
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
  <div class="showcase-content">
  <!-- For dynamic height to work in webkit you need to set the width and height of images in the source.
  Usually works to only set the dimension of the first slide in the showcase. -->
- <img src="/images/05.jpg" alt="05" width="700px" height="600px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="05" width="700px" height="600px" />
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
- <img src="/images/05.jpg" alt="05" width="140px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/05.jpg" alt="05" width="140px" />
  <!-- The div below with the class .showcase-thumbnail-cover is used for the thumbnails active state. -->
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
  <!-- Put the slide content in a div with the class .showcase-content. -->
  <div class="showcase-content">
- <img src="/images/01.jpg" alt="01" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" />
  </div>
  <!-- Put the thumbnail content in a div with the class .showcase-thumbnail -->
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
- <img src="/images/01.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/01.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Put the caption content in a div with the class .showcase-caption -->
  <div class="showcase-caption">
  <h2>Be creative. Get Noticed!</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
  <div class="showcase-content">
- <img src="/images/04.jpg" alt="04" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="04" />
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
- <img src="/images/04.jpg" alt="04" width="140px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/04.jpg" alt="04" width="140px" />
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
  <div class="showcase-content">
- <img src="/images/03.jpg" alt="03" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="03" />
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
- <img src="/images/03.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/03.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Each child div in #showcase represents a slide -->
  <div class="showcase-slide">
  <div class="showcase-content">
- <img src="/images/02.jpg" alt="02" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="02" />
  </div>
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail">
- <img src="/images/02.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/02.jpg" alt="01" width="140px" />
  <div class="showcase-thumbnail-cover"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Put the tooltips in a div with the class .showcase-tooltips. -->
  <div class="showcase-tooltips">
  <!-- Each anchor in .showcase-tooltips represents a tooltip. The coords attribute represents the position of the tooltip. -->
  <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="634,130">
  <!-- The content of the anchor-tag is displayed in the tooltip. -->
  This is a tooltip that displays the anchor html in a nice way.
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="200,440">
  This is a tooltip that displays the anchor html in a nice way.
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="600,440">
  This is a tooltip that displays the anchor html in a nice way.
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.awkward.se" coords="356, 172">
  <!-- You can add multiple elements to the anchor-tag which are display in the tooltip. -->
- <img src="/images/glasses.png" />
?           -
+ <img src="images/glasses.png" />
  <span style="display: block; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px 0 3px 0; text-align: center;">
  White Glasses: 500$
  </span>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;">
  <a href="http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin">
  Click here to download and learn more about this jQuery plugin.
  </a>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
>>>
```

Logs are below: I run the app, click the projects link to go to the /projects/ page, where the gallery correctly displays 05.jpg Then you can see me clicking across to 01 and 04.jpg, then back to 05.jpg (05.jpg is the only one that isn't blacked out). Thumbnails work though.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py" .
WARNING  2012-04-22 23:50:20,888 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:21,914 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server: appengine.google.com
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:21,921 appcfg.py:581] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:23,601 appcfg.py:599] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:23,891 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:650] Running application dev~mark-smith-app on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:23,891 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:652] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
WARNING  2012-04-22 23:50:24,252 py_zipimport.py:139] Can't open zipfile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg: IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyfacebook-1.0a2-py2.7.egg'
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:25,663 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:25,744 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /stylesheets/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:25,825 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/home.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:25,960 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,076 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /projects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,164 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,257 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /stylesheets/jquery.aw-showcase.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,414 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/05.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,499 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/black-opacity-40.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,572 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,651 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/white-opacity-80.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,730 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,811 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,891 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/02.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:32,973 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/glasses.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:33,045 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/arrows-small.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:33,122 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/arrows.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:33,220 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:38,493 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:44,198 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:46,536 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/03.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:52,927 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/04.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:54,806 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/01.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2012-04-22 23:50:57,243 dev_appserver.py:2865] "GET /images/05.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: So since there is hardly any difference between what index4.html servers up and what projects.html servers up, I'm confused why the gallery doesn't work at 127.0.0.1/projects/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nearly impossible to tell from the information given what the precise cause is, but there is one big difference between the development server and the production server: the development server is single-threaded, so if it is not possible for a request to finish before the requests for the images come in, eventually the browsers will time out and no-longer try to render the images.

It would be useful to see the logs that are written out by the development server.

Comment: I have added logs to the bottom of the question. You can see in the log i navigate to /projects/ and then i navigate through some pictures on the slide and then back to the start of the slide. Only 05.jpg displays correctly. (thumbnails work though)

Comment: What do you suggest I do if it is a problem with being single-threaded? Use ajax instead, or just continue developing my website with the gallery broken in offline mode, but knowing it will work fine on appspot

Comment: I just noticed 127.0.0.1/projects/ works in IE 7. It still doesn't work in chrome when I tried "C:\...your path...\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-preconnect

Comment: sorry for spamming you with comments. I think I'll Just use IE7 to test this page offline. And trust that everything works on appspot. Is there anything else you have to say?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that if IE7 works for offline that it's not worth delving in too deeply, as you might pour lots of time into figuring out exactly what the problem is but find no particular resolution.